# IK And Copy Transforms Changing Position

Tags: pose-mode

I have a problem with Copy Transforms and IK.

When I turn them on they will change the position in *Object* and *Pose Mode*

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a circular dependency, which leads to unexpected behaviours: Your IK bone is child of a bone of the IK chain (probably the forearm, so its loc is controlled by the IK chain while IK bone itself is controlling the IK chain as well.

In this setup the IK bone is redundant: start with deleting it, add a clavicle bone, set the wrist bone and the arm bone child of the clavicle bone, delete the IK constraint on the wirst bone and add an IK constraint to the forearm bone, targeting the wirst, with a chain lenght of 2, so its influence is limited to arm and forearm, not extending to clavicle. Use the wrist bone to pilot loc and rot of the hand and the IK chain on the arm.